# Issue trying to build PocketSphinx for Android using the NDK on Windows with Cygwin

Tags: android, android-ndk, android-ndk-r5

I'm currently trying to build the PocketSphinx library for Android using the NDK on Windows with Cygwin. I have the PocketSphinxAndroidDemo project code. I also have the pocketsphinx and shpinxbase projects as sub folders of the E:/Development/CMUSphinx folder.

I'm trying to build using ndk-build from the project folder. The Android.mk file in the /jni/ folder of the project looks like this -

```
# Build the native component of the PocketSphinx library for Android.

# You MUST change this to the absolute path of the directory containing
# sphinxbase and pocketsphinx source code.
SPHINX_PATH := E:/Development/CMUSphinx

# Copy this Android.mk along with pocketsphinx_wrap.c and the contents of the 'edu' folder
# built by swig to the jni/ directory of your Android project.
BASE_PATH := $(call my-dir)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_C_INCLUDES := $(SPHINX_PATH)/sphinxbase/include/android $(SPHINX_PATH)/sphinxbase/include
LOCAL_CFLAGS += -DHAVE_CONFIG_H
LOCAL_CFLAGS += -DANDROID_NDK

LOCAL_PATH := $(SPHINX_PATH)/sphinxbase/src/libsphinxbase/util
LOCAL_MODULE := sphinxutil

LOCAL_SRC_FILES := \
 bio.c \
 bitvec.c \
 case.c \
 ckd_alloc.c \
 cmd_ln.c \
 dtoa.c \
 err.c \
 errno.c \
 f2c_lite.c \
 filename.c \
 genrand.c \
 glist.c \
 hash_table.c \
 heap.c \
 huff_code.c \
 info.c \
 listelem_alloc.c \
 logmath.c.arm \
 matrix.c \
 mmio.c \
 pio.c \
 profile.c \
 sbthread.c \
 strfuncs.c \
 utf8.c

include $(BUILD_STATIC_LIBRARY)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_C_INCLUDES := $(SPHINX_PATH)/sphinxbase/include/android $(SPHINX_PATH)/sphinxbase/include
LOCAL_CFLAGS += -DHAVE_CONFIG_H
LOCAL_CFLAGS += -DANDROID_NDK

LOCAL_PATH := $(SPHINX_PATH)/sphinxbase/src/libsphinxbase/fe
LOCAL_MODULE := sphinxfe
LOCAL_ARM_MODE := arm

LOCAL_SRC_FILES := \
 fe_interface.c \
 fe_sigproc.c \
 fe_warp_affine.c \
 fe_warp.c \
 fe_warp_inverse_linear.c \
 fe_warp_piecewise_linear.c \
 fixlog.c

include $(BUILD_STATIC_LIBRARY)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_C_INCLUDES := $(SPHINX_PATH)/sphinxbase/include/android $(SPHINX_PATH)/sphinxbase/include
LOCAL_CFLAGS += -DHAVE_CONFIG_H
LOCAL_CFLAGS += -DANDROID_NDK

LOCAL_PATH := $(SPHINX_PATH)/sphinxbase/src/libsphinxbase/feat
LOCAL_MODULE := sphinxfeat

LOCAL_SRC_FILES := \
 agc.c \
 cmn.c \
 cmn_prior.c \
 feat.c \
 lda.c

include $(BUILD_STATIC_LIBRARY)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_C_INCLUDES := $(SPHINX_PATH)/sphinxbase/include/android $(SPHINX_PATH)/sphinxbase/include
LOCAL_CFLAGS += -DHAVE_CONFIG_H
LOCAL_CFLAGS += -DANDROID_NDK

LOCAL_PATH := $(SPHINX_PATH)/sphinxbase/src/libsphinxbase/lm
LOCAL_MODULE := sphinxlm

LOCAL_SRC_FILES := \
 fsg_model.c \
 jsgf.c \
 jsgf_parser.c \
 jsgf_scanner.c \
 lm3g_model.c \
 ngram_model_arpa.c \
 ngram_model_dmp.c \
 ngram_model_set.c \
 ngram_model.c

include $(BUILD_STATIC_LIBRARY)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_C_INCLUDES := $(SPHINX_PATH)/sphinxbase/include/android $(SPHINX_PATH)/sphinxbase/include \
     $(SPHINX_PATH)/pocketsphinx/include
LOCAL_CFLAGS += -DHAVE_CONFIG_H
LOCAL_CFLAGS += -DANDROID_NDK

LOCAL_PATH := $(SPHINX_PATH)/pocketsphinx/src/libpocketsphinx
LOCAL_MODULE := pocketsphinx

LOCAL_SRC_FILES := \
 acmod.c     \
 bin_mdef.c    \
 blkarray_list.c   \
 dict.c     \
 dict2pid.c    \
 fsg_history.c   \
 fsg_lextree.c   \
 fsg_search.c   \
 hmm.c.arm     \
 mdef.c     \
 ms_gauden.c.arm    \
 ms_mgau.c.arm    \
 ms_senone.c.arm    \
 ngram_search.c   \
 ngram_search_fwdtree.c \
 ngram_search_fwdflat.c \
 phone_loop_search.c  \
 pocketsphinx.c \
 ps_lattice.c   \
 ps_mllr.c    \
 ptm_mgau.c.arm    \
 s2_semi_mgau.c.arm   \
 tmat.c     \
 vector.c

include $(BUILD_STATIC_LIBRARY)

# Create the dynamic library wrapper
include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_C_INCLUDES := $(SPHINX_PATH)/sphinxbase/include/android $(SPHINX_PATH)/sphinxbase/include \
     $(SPHINX_PATH)/pocketsphinx/include
LOCAL_CFLAGS += -DHAVE_CONFIG_H
LOCAL_CFLAGS += -DANDROID_NDK

LOCAL_PATH := $(BASE_PATH)
LOCAL_MODULE := pocketsphinx_jni

LOCAL_SRC_FILES := pocketsphinx_wrap.c

PRIVATE_WHOLE_STATIC_LIBRARIES := \
 $(call static-library-path,sphinxutil) \
 $(call static-library-path,sphinxfe) \
 $(call static-library-path,sphinxfeat) \
 $(call static-library-path,sphinxlm) \
 $(call static-library-path,pocketsphinx)
LOCAL_STATIC_LIBRARIES := sphinxutil sphinxfe sphinxfeat sphinxlm pocketsphinx

include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```

When I run the ndk-build command I get the following error:

```
build-binary.mk:197: *** target pattern contains no '%'. Stop.
```

I can build all the ndk samples just fine. Any clue what's causing this error? Many thanks in advance!

Comment: @Chris - Can you please post this as an answer? You mentioned drive letters and paths and that actually got me to my right answer. I'd like to be able to mark your answer as the correct one :) I added SPHINX_PATH := $(shell cygpath -u $(SPHINX_PATH)) Under the SPHINX_PATH declaration and now all works great! Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you know if this project has been previously built using cygwin with success? Cygwin has a number of oddities, from the awkward combination of windows drive letters with unix paths, to interpreting an inadvertent double slash in an assembled path unusually, and more. You could try the /cygdrive/e/ type of path instead of a drive letter, but who knows if that will help.

Comment: This answer got me to the right place. I added SPHINX_PATH := $(shell cygpath -u $(SPHINX_PATH)) Under the SPHINX_PATH declaration and now all works great! Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Jason, Edit jni/Android.mk file

Change Line 162 :

```
LOCAL_STATIC_LIBRARIES := sphinxutil sphinxfe sphinxfeat sphinxlm pocketsphinx
```

to :

```
LOCAL_STATIC_LIBRARIES := pocketsphinx sphinxlm sphinxfeat sphinxfe sphinxutil
```

That will resolve your issue.

Answer (score 1):

Jason,
you have to change your sphinx path to cygwin format i.e without ":"
change

```
SPHINX_PATH := E:/Development/CMUSphinx
```

to

```
SPHINX_PATH := /cygdrive/e/Development/CMUSphinx
```

this will fix the error

Answer (score 0):

I used following link for Building Pocketsphinx On Android On Windows 
https://sites.google.com/site/opiatefuchs/home/pocketsphinxandroiddemo but it misses one step that @Hitesh mentioned about replacing LOCAL_STATIC_LIBRARIES in jni/Android.mk file and I was able to build to latest 0.8 version.. thanks @Hitesh